# Executing shell commands from a C program

Tags: bash, unix, c

Is it possible to write to the stdin of a running shell (Bash) using a C program? Actually I want to execute commands using `bash` from my C program without using one of the `exec*()` system calls.

Comment: Ultimately, you're going to need a `fork()` and an `exec*()` call to get the `bash` program running; there isn't any real alternative (unless you count [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html), and I don't).  There's then a question of organizing the plumbing on the `bash`, to handle standard input (from your program?) and standard output (to your program?) and standard error, and the correct shell options (`-i`?).  What sorts of commands do you anticipate executing in your captive shell?

Comment: I just want to take a string input from my program and send this string to any running instance of bash and that bash would do the execution for me and send the corresponding output to my program.

Comment: Note that you can't arbitrarily send your command to any arbitrary running instance of Bash; most of them are tied up doing someone else's work and are in the wrong current directory and have the wrong environment set and so on. You will need to run your own shell; you don't have to run a new shell for each separate command if you're careful, but you will need to `fork()` and `exec*()` the `bash` you communicate with. You'll want two or three pipes (standard input for shell, standard output of shell, possibly separate standard error of shell), and you'll need to think about how you read them.

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/echo` is a C program, usually.

```
/bin/echo ls | sh
```

Voilà!  A C program just wrote to the standard input of a running shell, and a command was executed.  This is demonstrably possible.

`man popen` is now your friend.  (Any more is really beyond SuperUser's scope, as is discussion of other things such as `system()` and the need for quoting.)

Comment: There is also a program `/bin/echo`; however, most shells have a built-in command `echo`.

Comment: Using a built-in would muddy the answer unnecessarily.  Whereas one can point to `/bin/echo` and say "That's a compiled C program, in that file, there.".